# Open JdbcTemplate connection in read only mode?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, readonly, jdbctemplate

is it possible to open a JdbcTemplate connection in read only mode, so that I can't perform any changes to the underlying data source?

Comment: Are you talking about the Spring Framework?

Comment: Yes, I do talk about the Spring framework.

Answer (score 4):

Use Spring Transactions and declare the transaction as readOnly. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

Answer (score 2):

I use a helper method like this

```
private void setConnectionReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().setReadOnly(readOnly);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: at what point should this be called? just before execution of the query? also, how does it work with a connection pool and concurrent threads?

Comment: i call it right before the call to jdbcTemplate.query to set, and right after to un-set

Comment: yes but is there a guarantee that when .query is issued, it would use the same connection on which read-only was set?

Comment: maybe i'm wrong but you usually only have 1 connection.  that connection may be a pool. and there's no way to deal with the config each 'pool connector' (not sure correct term for these)  so i believe so.

Comment: no. it depends on the underlying datasource. If it doesn't support connection pooling, it will return that only connection. otherwise, it might return a different connection than the one that was set to read-only. More info at [Supported Connection Pools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.sql.datasource.connection-pool)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the JDBC connection API allows this.

You have two choices:

1. GRANT appropriate permissions on the
   database level to only allow SELECT
   operations;
2. Use Spring AOP and Security to intercept calls to write operations on the DAO and forbid them for certain roles.

The second choice is obviously more flexible and in the spirit of Spring's natural idiom.